# Extract Audio from Video in Swift

Tags: swift, audio, video, avassetexportsession

I'm new to Swift from Objective-C and have hit a wall.  I need to extract audio from a `.mov` file so I can then run this through speech to text processing.  The code I have so far creates a file but it does not contain audio.  This is the code I have so far

```
private var audioFilePath: URL!

private func createAudioFile(){
    let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    self.audioFilePath = url.appendingPathComponent("myAudio.m4a")

    let theAsset = AVAsset(url: self.outputFilePath)

    let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: theAsset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
    exporter?.outputURL = self.audioFilePath
    exporter?.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4

    print("file path = ", self.audioFilePath)

    exporter?.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {
        print("exporter?.status\(exporter?.status)")
    })
}
```

Thanks for your help!